# Como obtengo rol del usuario logueado con JavaScrip?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Tengo una página en php, laravel y javascrip. La idea es que al momento de cargar el formulario, se verifique cual es el rol del usuario logueado. Si es un usuario rol "2" oculte unos campos. Si es un usuario rol "1" los muestra o los deja. Hasta el momento solo lo he logrado obteniendo el rol y colocándolo en un campo, que luego valido:

[image: imagen del código.]

La función "ocultar_campo()" es llamada en el  , la cual se ejecuta al momento de cargar la página. El código funciona así como está. Pero lo que quiero es que verifique automáticamente con el rol, y no mediante el campo que tengo. Estoy utilizando este código para obtener el rol pero no me funciona: if auth()->user()->rol ==2{
Que error tendría o cual sería el código correcto?. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Luego presiona en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/324295) y agrega un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de tu código (como texto y con su correspondiente formato) para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Probaste a debuguear e ir viendo qué valores te da?